# how to declare method return value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, methods, return, return-value

I've made a class named `Cls_ICCID` where I declare the method in `Update_Status` which returns a byRef variable.

---

**Cls_ICCID**

```vb
Public Sub Update_Status(**ByRef massege As String**, ByVal ICCID_No As Integer, ByVal status As Integer)
        Try
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim sql As String
            Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
            myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TEHRANI\TEHRANI;Initial Catalog=GSMProduction;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1"
            sql = "UPDATE Tbl_ICCID SET Status=status WHERE ICCID=ICCIDNo"
            myConnection = New SqlConnection(sql)
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            massege = "SeccessFully"
        Catch ex As Exception
            massege = "server Error"
        End Try
    End Sub
```

And then I execute that method when a textbox change event triggers:

```vb
 Private Sub Txt_ICCID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txt_ICCID.TextChanged
     Dim clsICCID As Cls_ICCID
     clsICCID.Update_Status(lblError.Text, Txt_ICCID.Text, 1)
 End Sub
```

But this gives me the exception:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
>   [image]
>   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is completely unrelated to the code you’ve posted. Furthermore, this code is very odd, to put it politely.

Comment: how do i do? are you suggestion for me?

Comment: i want if operation with database is disconnect , in lblerror that put in my page, wrote"server Error", but i don't know how to declare return value in method

Comment: Change your project properties and set OPTION STRICT ON and check the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be honest, as konrad said you should really work on the basics if you want to use such kind of code.

haven't tried the code out, but i think you want something like

```
Public Function Update_Status(iccidNo As Integer, status As Integer) As String
    Const sql As String = "UPDATE Tbl_ICCID SET Status=@status WHERE ICCID=@ICCIDNo"
    Const connstr As String = "Data Source=TEHRANI\TEHRANI;Initial Catalog=GSMProduction;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1"
    Try
        Using myConnection = New SqlConnection()
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connstr
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ICCIDNo", iccidNo)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Update_Status = "Successfully"
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Update_Status = "server Error"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Update_Status = "server Error"
    End Try
End Function
```

but personally i would handle the exceptions not that way and return a boolean.

Comment: i dont think that the exception will be thrown by my function. Put a break in the exceptions there, does the debugger stop there? Maybe you post some more code (the code behind the Exception in the image)

Comment: when arrived to "returnValue = Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text, 1)" , jump to exception

Comment: @SaharKiyan: what data does Txt_ICCID.Text contain? Try convert it to Integer like  returnValue = Update_Status(Convert.ToInt32(Txt_ICCID.Text), 1)

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you specifically ask is returning value in a method. Instead of `Sub` you must declare it like `Function` and then return the value with `return`:

```
Public Function Update_Status(ICCID_No As Integer, status As Integer) As String
    '...

    return massege
End Function
```

And then catch the value:

```
lblError.Text = clsICCID.Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text, 1)
```

Comment: @SaharKiyan Maybe `Txt_ICCID.Text` is not a number. Probably the error came in that way. In any case, you should convert it to number first.

Comment: yes, i change type of ICCID_No to string, and in clsICCID.Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text.tostring(), 1)!! but give me exception:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @SaharKiyan There is no need to use `.ToString` in `Txt_ICCID.Text` because is already a String. Check the control `Txt_ICCID` or post the code related in order to us to help you. The error is in that side.

Answer (score 0):

I should use from Function instead of sub method. because sub method is void.

Answer (score 0):

For a method to return a value you need to declare your method as a function, instead of sub. 
For example:

```
Public Function Update_Status(ByVal ICCID_No As Integer, ByVal status As Integer) As String
    Return "errorMessage"
End Function
```

And can then invoke it like this:

```
returnValue = Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text, 1)
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

**But it also seems that your parameters might not match up: sending a String as an Integer?**

Comment: when arrived to "returnValue = Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text, 1)" , jump to exception

Comment: If Txt_ICCID.Text is a string, you should not send it as input to an Integer parameter.

Comment: yes, i change type of ICCID_No to string, and in clsICCID.Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text.tostring(), 1)!! but give me exception:"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: maybe Txt_ICCID or Txt_ICCID.Text is null.. Set a breakpoint in the debugger and check their values.

Comment: thank you for spend your time for my question.i increase your reputation,but decrease it